# optimize sql code

Tags: sql, oracle11g

guys  i have  to select every  employees,who has  salary more then avarage salary in his department,there one code   which does  this problem,it is here

```
select * from
(select  e.first_name || ' ' || e.last_name ENAME,
d.department_name,e.salary, trunc(e.salary-avg(salary) over (partition by
  e.department_id)) sal_dif
  from employees e,departments d
  where  e.department_id=d.department_id)
  where sal_dif>0
```

when i run it,it works fine and also cost of this  code is 6 in my computer,i have tried to do it on another way,like this

```
select   first_name || ' '|| last_name,salary
  from
  (select first_name || ' ' || last_name,salary ,avg(salary) over (partition by  department_id) avg_salary
  from employees )
  where salary>avg_salary;
```

i am surprised  that,inspite of  existence of  last_name and first_name in database,,error

```
shows me ORA-00904: "LAST_NAME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 29
```

why?can i  rewrite first code in other way?thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alias to identify the column:

```
select   full_name,salary
  from
  (select first_name || ' ' || last_name as full_name,salary ,avg(salary) over (partition by  department_id) avg_salary
  from employees )
  where salary>avg_salary;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select name,salary
from
(select first_name || ' ' || last_name as name,salary ,avg(salary) over (partition by     department_id) avg_salary
  from employees )
  where salary>avg_salary;
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to aliasing the combined column inside the subquery, don't combine the columns in the subquery - instead, replace the concatenation with a `,`, like so:

```
select   first_name || ' '|| last_name,salary
from
  (select first_name, last_name, salary,
          avg(salary) over (partition by  department_id) avg_salary
   from employees)
where salary>avg_salary;
```